# JqGrid - how to hide search icon in pager when there is advanced search on button click outside of grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using JqGrid version 4.13.6. for the grid in which I have implemented advanced search on click of a button that is outside the grid.

```
$(function () {
     $('#btnAdvSearch').click(
          function () {
              jQuery("#SummaryListGrid").jqGrid('searchGrid', {
                  multipleSearch: true,
                  showQuery: false,
                  caption: "Advanced Search Summary Data ...",
                  closeAfterSearch: true,
                  sopt: ['cn', 'nc', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'in', 'ni', 'ew', 'en'],
                  columns: [
                      getColumnByName.call($grid, 'LongTitle'),
                      getColumnByName.call($grid, 'Code'),
                      getColumnByName.call($grid, 'Description'),                         
                      getColumnByName.call($grid, 'ShortTitle')                         
                  ]
              })
```

In the pager, i just need to show refresh icon.

```
jQuery("#SummaryListGrid").navGrid('#SummaryListpager', {
  edit: false, 
  add: false, 
  del: false, 
  refresh: true, 
  refreshtext: "Reload Summary List", 
  Search: false 
})
```

But, search icon also is seen. How do I hide the search icon in the pager?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just fix the case of `search: false` property of `navGrid`: from `Search: false` to `search: false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg !